# Creating a linkedlist in C but what would be the ending condition for the function i have created as its not exiting

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to data structure and just not getting the working of linked list, so I am creating a linkedlist myself and it differs from the one in the book, but cant understand that where is the issue in my code as its not exiting. What needs to be rectified
Here is my code

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
void addAtBegining(int data,struct node* head){
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = head->next;
    head->next = new_node;
}
void display(struct node* head){
    while(head->next!=NULL){
        head = head->next;
        printf("%d ",head->data);
    }
}
void main(){
    struct node* list = NULL;
    addAtBegining(2,list);
    addAtBegining(3,list);
    addAtBegining(4,list);
    addAtBegining(5,list);
    addAtBegining(6,list);
    display(list);
}
```

Comment: `struct node* list = NULL;` --> `struct node dummy = {0, NULL}; struct node *list = &dummy;`

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behaviour: You have `struct node* list = NULL` but then you pass `list` to `addAtBegining`, which is received in the parameter `head` and then performs a `head->next`.

Either

- Initialise head
- Add code to addAtBegining to return head pointer, if null then allocate
- Add double pointers to update `head`

For example you can do the following

```
struct node* list = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
list->data = 0xdeafbabe;
list->next = NULL;
```

Then use your existing code.

What this does is to just ad a dummy head node with junk data. As your print routine skips the head node anyway. This will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to initialize `head`. Can fix this changing `struct node* list = NULL;` with following code:

```
struct node* head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->data = 0;
head->next = NULL;
struct node* list = head;
```

Answer (score 1):

you didnt set head pointer in the code. so this pointer is not recognised in other function.

```
struct node{
   int data;
   struct node* next;
}*head;

// you dont need to put the head pointer in the parameters if you just add in the beginning of the single linked list.
void addAtBegining(int data){
     struct node* new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     // if head is empty then set the head first.
     if(head==NULL){
        head = new_node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
     }
     // if head is not empty then set the new_node->data and set that node as the new head
     new_node->data = data;
     new_node->next = head;
     head = new_node;
}

void display(struct node* head){
    while(head!=NULL){
      printf("%d ",head->data);
      head = head->next;
    }
}
```